# c# compare two numbers got from two files

Tags: c#

in c# i need to compare 2 numbers one from a local file, and one another from a downloaded file like a Patcher.

if I use Streamreader c# sad to me that he can't convert string into INT.

are there a solution for this?
file a contains the value "1" , the file b contains the value "2"

so if b>a then download the new files catch from another updater file.

thanks

Comment: How did you try to convert to int ? Did you look at the string? Maybe there are control characters included?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using for reading the number? And include the exact contents of one of the files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void CompareVersions()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    var serverVersion = client.DownloadString("http://yourwebsite.com/version.txt");

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(serverVersion) > Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()))
        {
            // server version bigger
        }
        else
        {
            // up to date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tks, just tested. this solution take me out managing two files

Comment: An answer with code for copy and pasting without any explanations may help the OP in their current question, but probably does not help them understand how this problem, and similar problems, can be solved. This is even more true for future visitors with similar, but not the same problem, who cannot benefit from a copy-and-paste answer at all.

Comment: @David/ update your answer to include explanation and you might reverse your downvotes since I think it is a decent piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only number in the file, you can use `File.ReadAllText` (or `File.ReadAllLines` in a multiline file) and convert to `int` like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\t.txt");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(lines[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use the Convert.ToInt32 method. 
If your file contains olny one number, you could use the File.ReadAllLine method, insted of streamreader.